# After create MongoDB view, ODBC can't display this view

Tags: powerbi, odbc, mongodb-biconnector

For example, I have a MongoDB with 3 collections and 1 view.

```
Collections:
  products,
  catalogs,
  projects

Views:
  view_project_product_catalog
```

After I create a new view in DB and reconnect BI connector, I still can't see the new view in ODBC when editing Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

There's a setting in BI Connector called "**refreshIntervalSecs**"

Default value is 0 which means don't refresh.

So your new view won't be known by BI Connector.

Just give a value and wait. You will be able to get value through ODBC.

### Atlas User

If you are using MongoDB Atlas, the setting in next to BI connector (where you can see the charge price above.)

No default value in this field.
Sample Refresh Interval(Optional)

[image]